# How to redirect user when clicking on a Chart element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-chartjs

I am using [react-chartJs-2](https://github.com/jerairrest/react-chartjs-2) library to display the charts. Suppose, user clicks on the bar/Doughnut chart section he must be redirected to a specific page. Following is the code I have done for DoughnutChart:

1. ChartDisplay.jsx

```
<div className="DonutChartSection" >
   <Doughnut labelArray = {this.state.labelArr} DataArray = {this.state.DoughnutDataArr} colorArray = {this.state.DoughnutColorArr} title={"Employees"} />
</div>
```

2. Doughnut.jsx

   ```
   import React from 'react';
   import {Doughnut} from 'react-chartjs-2';

   Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontStyle = 'Bold';  
   Chart.defaults.global.defaultLegendPosition = 'left';

   export default class DoughnutChartView extends React.Component{
     constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { };
     }

     render() {
       let data = {
           labels: this.props.labelArray,
           datasets: [{
               data: this.props.DataArray,
               backgroundColor: this.props.colorArray,
               hoverBackgroundColor: this.props.colorArray,
           }]
       } 
       return (
         <div>
         <span className="titleName" >{this.props.title}</span> 
           <Doughnut data={data}  />
         </div>
       );
     }
   };
   ```

I went through the github page and found the following event which can be used for click event but can't figure out how can I use it in my code.

> https://github.com/jerairrest/react-chartjs-2#onelementsclick--getelementsatevent-function

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Indeed, you actually answered your question already: `onElementsClick` can be used to execute an action when user clicks on an element of the chart. `onElementsClick` is a prop of the chart itself, so:

```
<Doughnut data={data} onElementsClick={elems => {
    // if required to build the URL, you can 
    // get datasetIndex and value index from an `elem`:
    console.log(elems[0]._datasetIndex + ', ' + elems[0]._index);
    // and then redirect to the target page:
    window.location = "https://example.com";
}} />
```

Note that `elems` may include more than one element, for example in case of a stacked bar chart (in which case it includes all elements of a bar clicked).

Comment: Thanks a lot Timur for the apt example.

Comment: I am trying to add dynamic link in this way : `<Doughnut data={data} onElementsClick={data => {
         this.props.handleTabClick.bind(this.state.currentObj, 'view_page', this.props.pageId, 'ei')
        }} />` but nothing is happening. I have included `handleTabClick` and `pageId` in the Donughnut page

Comment: Hm. I'm not sure why you use `bind` - this only binds `this` in the scope of the function, but doesn't call it. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind. Maybe what you need is `onElementsClick={data => { this.props.handleTabClick(this.state.currentObj, 'view_page', this.props.pageId, 'ei') }}`... Otherwise it is probably best to post this as a separate question with more context (handleTabClick function and how the component is used). Hope it helps.

Comment: how to get the element data which is being clicked? Ex. if the chart has `2 categories - manual, automation`. I want if user clicks on manual then manual to be returned .

Comment: Try logging to the console the argument received by `onElementsClick` and see its structure - this information is passed with this argument.

Answer (score 1):

here is a actually quick solution for clicking on a pie Chart

```
import { Pie } from 'react-chartjs-2'
        <Pie
            getElementAtEvent={(data) => {
                if(data.length >= 1){
                    const dataItem: any  = data[0]
                    const index = dataItem.index
                    const foundLabel = props.labels[index]
                    // redirect or do stuff
                }
            }}
```